# Symfony (3.4.2) - Error: Controller "fos_rest.exception.twig_controller" cannot be fetched from the container because it is private

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-3.4

I'm on an api project using FOSRestBundle on Symfony 3.4 and have some error when I want to use my own error messages. 
It says me:

*Controller "fos_rest.exception.twig_controller" cannot be fetched from the container because it is private. Did you forget to tag the service with "controller.service_arguments"*

I'm stuck on this error, I think a config is missing but I don't understand which one...

Thanks

Comment: Consider updating your question with the FOS lines from your composer.json file.  If any of them have '@dev' in them then remove the '@dev' and run composer update and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I don't have the @dev in my composer.json require: "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3"

Comment: Okay.  Go into app/config/services.yml and set public:true under _defaults.  This is just another guess and it may cause more trouble than it is worth.  And while you at it, verify you have    templating: engines: ['twig'] in your framework config.

Comment: @Cerad, my _defaults public is already on true. It seems to be a config to put on the exception controller but I don't realy know how because of my noobie's skills^^

Comment: Post a link to the docs you are following to config your own error message.

Comment: It is a french course on OpenClassRooms: https://openclassrooms.com/courses/construisez-une-api-rest-avec-symfony/gestion-des-erreurs

Comment: Oh.  French.  That explains it.  Just kidding.  All I can suggest is that you read through the official docs and see if there is anything useful.  S3.3/3.4 do have quite a few changes that might not be covered in the tutorial. https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/error_pages.html

Comment: @Cerad Ahah new on Symfony AND french :/... But isn't Symfony french? :p Ok thanks, I'll read it again to see if I didn't miss something somewhere...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution:
Add to your config.yml, in fos_rest:

```
fos_rest:
    //
    exception:
        //
        exception_controller: 'fos_rest.exception.controller:showAction'
```